# Preventing Devise/ActionMailer from sending confirmation email but still creating the token

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to send a custom Email, later and I need to keep the created token in the database. If I use `skip_confirmation!` it will not create the token but will prevent the email to be sent.

How can I just stop the email but not the confirmation process ?

Comment: How much later will you send your email? The token in the database is encrypted so you won't be able to get hold of it in plaintext form if you were planning to read it from there at some later point.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `skip_confirmation_notification!` instead of `skip_confirmation!`.  This should stop the email being sent, but the confirmation token itself should still be generated and saved.   However, depending on how you intend to handle things, you may need to consider the cases:

1. Where they resend confirmation instructions (unless you've disabled that), because it looks like that won't be stopped by `skip_confirmation_notification!`.
2. Where they change their email address which requires reconfirmation (if reconfirmable), though it looks like that respects `skip_confirmation_notification!` if you've just called it.

Also, as I said in my comment on the question, confirmation tokens are encrypted in the database so if you were planning on pulling it out of the database at some time later, you won't be able to.  You need to get hold of the plaintext value of the token for insertion into your custom email (if that's your plan) while the object is still in existence because it's a transient attribute.

I assume there's a reason you can't just replace devise's standard confirmation email with your custom one?  Then you wouldn't need to bother skipping the sending.